# Multi-finger Capable iOS Web App

Tags: ios, multi-touch, web-app

Some time ago, I had a bookmark on my iPhone for a WebApp I believe to be called "Sparkie". It was a web app that would display electric arcs for every finger that tapped the screen, and would draw lines in-between multiple fingers. It goes without saying that it appears I've lost the bookmark.

In my attempts to search for it, I have found [Matt Gemmell's Multi-Finger Test app](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/05/09/ipad-multi-touch), but I am not able to deploy it to my iPad because I am not a paying iOS developer.

Anyone out there know of the WebApp I'm searching for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I just clicked "Older Comments" on Matt Gemmell's blog, and found the link. You have GOT to be kidding me.

http://spark.attrakt.se/